# How to convert duplicate keys containing multiple list to a dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

My dictionary looks like below. From below dictionary one can see that the key "Column A" contains Multiple values 1,2,3. I would to convert below dictionary to pandas dataframe such that there is duplicate values for Column A. Below is my expected output. I tried using pandas function pd.Dataframe. However, receieved and error that says "ValueError: arrays must all be same length". Please advice how to proceed with dataframe creation.

Thanks in advance for your time!

**My Dictionary**

```
my_dict={"Column A":[1,2,3],"ABC":456,"CDE":[12,11]}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Column A       1
Column A       2
Column A       3
ABC            456
CDE            12
CDE            11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
my_dict = {"Column A": [1, 2, 3], "ABC": 456, "CDE": [12, 11]}

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": my_dict.keys(), "col2": my_dict.values()})
df = df.explode("col2")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       col1 col2
0  Column A    1
0  Column A    2
0  Column A    3
1       ABC  456
2       CDE   12
2       CDE   11
```

Comment: Receiving an error that says 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: Explode is available in 0.25.0 and newer [What’s new in 0.25.0 (July 18, 2019)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#series-explode-to-split-list-like-values-to-rows)

Comment: Great. Thank you HenryEcker and Andrej Kesely!  I was using different version of pandas :)

Comment: One more question..How to remove index column ? I tried using df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True). But couldn't get rid of index. Any suggestion ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Following the question in the comments:
In DataFrames and Series, index is always there.

if you want, you can set one of your columns as index, or you can reset it, but it is impossible to remove it.
if you want to set col1 as your index, try:

```
df.set_index('col1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

**code**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict([(k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in my_dict.items()])
                  ).T.stack().reset_index().drop(columns = ['level_1'])
```

**result**

```
    level_0      0
0  Column A    1.0
1  Column A    2.0
2  Column A    3.0
3       ABC  456.0
4       CDE   12.0
5       CDE   11.0
```